# Pandas idxmax - top n values

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'consumption': [10.51, 103.11, 55.48], 'co2_emissions': [37.2, 19.66, 1712]}, index=['Pork', 'Wheat Products', 'Beef'])
df['Max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
df
```

I need to find the n largest values. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35872840/4399016) there is a technique using apply/lambda.
But it returns error.

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.abs().nlargest(2).index.tolist(), axis=1,skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
```

> TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'numeric_only'

Is there any way to obtain top N results using idxmax? Is there any way to overcome this error got when using apply lambda method?

Comment: When you're getting errors like `"...got an unexpected keyword argument"` your first point of inquiry should be the documentation and `apply()` doesn't have such argument., at least the current version.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with `idxmax()`? Why can't you just use it? Why use `apply` at all?

Comment: I need top N results. There is no documentation example for top N results in idxmax.

Comment: The example included in the attached url does not have these arguments passed. But I need to use these. That is the question. How to overcome the apply method's short comings? "skipna=True, numeric_only=True"

Comment: So why not just use `sort_values()` for specific column and then return indices of top 5 rows? `df.sort_values('a', ascending=True).iloc[:5, :].index` Something like this should work

Comment: This may not be the most elegant of solutions. There has to be a better way. I will be using timeseries data. Sorting other columns may result in problems later.

Comment: Well, then provide an example of data where it **will** cause problems...

Comment: Please read [mre] and [ask], then edit your question to include a *complete* [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to passing the `skipna` and `numeric_only` parameters to `apply`.

You can fix it with:

```
(df.select_dtypes('number')
   .apply(lambda s: s.dropna().abs().nlargest(2)
                     .index.tolist(), axis=1)
 )
```

Output:

```
Pork              [co2_emissions, consumption]
Wheat Products    [consumption, co2_emissions]
Beef              [co2_emissions, consumption]
dtype: object
```

A more efficient approach using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

```
N = 2

tmp = df.select_dtypes('number')

out = pd.Series(
    np.take_along_axis(
        tmp.columns.to_numpy()[:, None],
        np.argpartition(tmp, -N)[:, -N:],
        axis=0
    )[:, ::-1].tolist(),
    index=df.index,
)
```

Comment: I intend to apply Apriori Algorithm - Association Analysis to this output to identify frequently occurring item set. This step would be very helpful.

Comment: I added a more efficient alternative with numpy

Comment: The numpy method gives error. InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), slice(-2, None, None))

Comment: Maybe you have less than 2 numeric columns? Please provide a reproducible example that triggers this error.